# Accessing topmost dialog

Tags: android, unit-testing

Is there a way to access the topmost AlertDialog/ProgressDialog?

I am writing unit tests for the android app and I would like to test if based on certain condition an AlertDialog with the specified message is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the right way to do this is to introduce mockable class that displays the dialogs for you (perhaps one already exists?  I'm following the unit-testing tag).  Then for your unit tests, you provide a class that intercepts the message and performs your checks.